# Resume current activity or create another one from notification

Tags: android, push-notification, notifications

I have two activities in my app.

The first one, which is `login` (the one which is started as Main/Launcher)
The second one, which contains fragments and so the main content. So `Login` activity starts `Main` activity.

When I receive a notification and click on it, I want to be able to handle those scenarios:

- resume app if it's in background (like user resume it like pressing home key) but without showing the launcher activity (login).
- launch app if it's not launched yet.

I tried with mode `singleTask` for both in `Manifest` and here the code in my `service`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, notificationId, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Then I pass `pendingIntent` in the `setContentIntent` method of the notification.

But when I click on the notification, and the app is already launched and in background, it restarts the Login activity (I don't want it) but resume the Main activity correctly.

Comment: I was able to solve a similar problem with use of `android:launchMode="singleTop"` in me manifest for my `MainActivity`, have you tried that?

Comment: Yep, I already tried but same result